# How to add a line in ggplot2 using geom_path in a bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote this code:

```
df = data.frame(a=c('A','A','B','B'),b=c('X','Y','X','Y'),c=c(1,2,3,2))

q = ggplot(df, aes(a, y=c,fill=b))+
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity")

path = data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(2,2))
q = q + geom_path(data=path,aes(x=x, y=y))
```

I want to get a plot that have a horizontal line that start at the junction of the first two bar and end at the junction of the last two bar at height(position in Y axis)2.

However,my code give me an error:

> "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found"

update:
Thanks to Chris, moving the "fill" to geom_bar solves the orignal problem. But now, a new problem happens. I changed my code to:

```
    library(ggplot2)
df=data.frame(a=c('A','A','B','B'),b=c('X','Y','X','Y'),c=c(1,2,3,2),err=c(.1,.2,.1,.2))
q = ggplot(df, aes(a, y=c))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=b),position=position_dodge(), stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=c-err,ymax=c+err), width=0.3, lwd = 1, position=position_dodge(0.9))

path = data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(2,2))
q = q + geom_path(data=path,aes(x=x, y=y))

print(q)
```

Because the "fill" is not in the original ggplot() function, the position of the error bar is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `aes` in your first `ggplot` call:

```
q <- ggplot(df, aes(a, y=c)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=b), position=position_dodge(), stat='identity')

path <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(2,2))
q <- q + geom_path(data=path,aes(x=x, y=y))
```

EDIT: added code for completeness

Comment: I can't tell, what changed about the plot?

Comment: Oh I see now, it draws a path from the second bar to the third. Cool.

Comment: @small_data88 if you include `size=2`, or `lty=2`, etc. you will see the difference more clearly.

Comment: I now have a new problem. I try to add error bar to by code. Since the "fill" argument is not in the ggplot(), the position of the error bars are messed up. Here is the code:"library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(a=c('A','A','B','B'),b=c('X','Y','X','Y'),c=c(1,2,3,2),err=c(.1,.2,.1,.2))
q = ggplot(df, aes(a, y=c))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=b),position=position_dodge(), stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=c-err,ymax=c+err), width=0.3, lwd = 1, position=position_dodge(0.9))


path = data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(2,2))
q = q + geom_path(data=path,aes(x=x, y=y))

print(q)"

Comment: Please accept this answer and open a new question if there are other issues.